# Add an angled badge to a WPF usercontrol

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on creation a wpf control that contain a badge like in the image below :
[image]

Here's the code I tried but it's not adjustable with window sizes

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="261" Margin="49,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359" Background="#FFF7EDED">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Hi there" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFA42828"  Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.8" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="-42.14,117.204,-16.176,101.754">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-30.771"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-31.015"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="13.961" Y="-8.394"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

I tried with the `Rectangle` control by changing it's X and Y axes but it wont work since I need something adjustable with the size of the control. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

basically it is a border, a diagonal line and a centered text. the only trick is to set correct coordinate for line, I used binding to `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` for that purpose

```
<Border Height="50" Name="brd" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid Name="bounds">
        <Line Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="2" 
          X1="0" Y1="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=bounds}" 
          X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=bounds}" Y2="0">
        </Line>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="24"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image: result]

Comment: Well I tried with the line but it won't work, it fails to detect the actual width and height. it is really strange I put the code in a user control. When I added your code to my control it renders the line till infinite. Any explanation. ?